# How to programatically close a JFace Dialog in Eclipse Application

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to programatically close a JFace Dialog in eclipse application. The Dialog is being created using a Handler:

```java
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        IWorkbenchWindow window =HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
        CustomDialog dialog = new CustomDialog(window.getShell());
        dialog.open();
}
```

Now the 'Custom Dialog' runs a background thread and I want to close this dialog once the background thread completes. Is there a way to do this programatically , similar to what we can do for editors and views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call the dialog `close()` method.

Note that you must do this in the User Interface thread so a background thread would need to use `Display.asyncExec`.